# SUM inside a CASE, retrieving “Not a group function of unique group”

Tags: sql, oracle

I got this query with alot of columns on the `Select` and resumed it to just A,B,C for the example . The same `CASE` query was working but now i need to do it with `SUM` on the fields of the `CASE`,  but get the error:

[image: ERROR in Portuguese language]

This is the error image in portuguese I think I translated it decently to :

> Not a group function of unique group

Simplified example:

```
SELECT A.qty, 
           A.ord, 
           B.ord,
           CASE WHEN SUM(A.qty) = 0 
                THEN 0
                ELSE round(SUM(A.qty) - SUM(A.ord) / (SUM(A.qty) * 0.01),2)
                END AS Percent
    FROM A
    INNER JOIN B 
        ON (A.COD = B.COD)
    GROUP BY A.qty, 
             A.ord, 
             B.ord
```

Being the original query:

```
SELECT CONC_LINHAS_12.CONCL_COD
,CONC_LINHAS_12.CONCL_ARTIGO
,CONC_LINHAS_12.CONCL_FORNECEDOR   
,CONC_LINHAS_12.CONCL_QUANT
,CONC_LINHAS_12.CONCL_QUANT_CGN
,CONC_LINHAS_12.CONCL_PUNIT
,CONC_LINHAS_12.CONCL_PUNIT_PBS
,CONC_LINHAS_12.CONCL_PTOTAL_ADJ
,CONC_LINHAS_12.CONCL_QTD_CONTROL
,CONC_LINHAS_12.CONCL_QTDVAL   
,CONC_LINHAS_12.CONCL_EL_QUANT
,CONC_LINHAS_12.CONCL_EL_QUANTSAT
,CONC_LINHAS_12.CONCL_EL_NCD_QUANT
,CONC_LINHAS_12.CONCL_EL_PTOTAL
,CONC_LINHAS_12.CONCL_EL_PTOTALSAT
,CONC_LINHAS_12.CONCL_EL_NCD_PTOTAL
,CONC_LINHAS_12.CONCL_COD_ANO_ANT   
,CONC_LINHAS_12.CONCL_ENCVAL_SIVA
,CONC_LINHAS_12.CONCL_ENCVAL_CIVA
,CONC_LINHAS_12.CONCL_ENCVALSAT_SIVA
,CONC_LINHAS_12.CONCL_ENCVALSAT_CIVA
,CONC_LINHAS_12.CONCL_ENCQTD
,CONC_LINHAS_12.CONCL_ENCQTDSAT
,CONC_CAB_12.CONC_LIG

,CASE 
    WHEN SUM(CONC_LINHAS_12.CONCL_QUANT) = 0
        THEN 0
    ELSE round((SUM(CONC_LINHAS_12.CONCL_QUANT) - SUM(CONC_LINHAS_12.CONCL_ENCQTD) / SUM(CONC_LINHAS_12.CONCL_QUANT) * 0.01), 2)
    END AS Percentagem 

FROM QRY_CONC_LINHAS_12 CONC_LINHAS_12
INNER JOIN CONC_CAB_12 CONC_CAB_12 ON (CONC_LINHAS_12.CONCL_CONCURSO = CONC_CAB_12.CONC_LIG)
INNER JOIN ARTIGOS_12 ARTIGOS_12 ON (CONC_LINHAS_12.CONCL_ARTIGO = ARTIGOS_12.ART_CODIGO)
INNER JOIN FORNECEDORES FORNECEDORES ON (CONC_LINHAS_12.CONCL_FORNECEDOR = FORNECEDORES.FOR_CODIGO)
INNER JOIN IVA IVA ON (CONC_LINHAS_12.CONCL_IVA = IVA.IVA_COD)
LEFT JOIN NPDM_CDM NPDM_CDM ON (CONC_LINHAS_12.CONCL_NPDM_CDM = NPDM_CDM.COD)
LEFT JOIN NPDM_NPDM NPDM_NPDM ON (NPDM_CDM.NPDM = NPDM_NPDM.COD)
INNER JOIN UNIDADES UNIDADES ON (ARTIGOS_12.ART_UNIDADE = UNIDADES.UNI_COD)
LEFT JOIN ART_FARM ART_FARM ON (ART_FARM.ART_COD = ARTIGOS_12.ART_CODIGO)
WHERE (1 = 1)
```

Comment: Note that tables have _columns_, not fields.

Comment: **order** is a reserved keyword that shouldnt be your column, probably it's **"order"**

Comment: Is not present on the query , I just used it for example, I'll change, thx

Comment: @PedroSilva . . . The query you have here looks fine.

Comment: Can you share the "exact" error message you have got

Comment: Your original query does not contain GROUP BY, so what do you expect from `SUM(CONC_LINHAS_12.CONCL_QUANT)`?

Answer (score 1):

you could use a subquery for sum  and the outer select for you logic 
And you should not group by a column used  in aggregation function ( the A.qty is used  in SUM())

```
select  t.order_a, 
      t.order_b,
      case when t.sum_qty = 0 THEN 0 
           else round(sum_qty -sum_order / (SUM(A.qty) * 0.01), 2)
      END percent 
FROM (
SELECT A.qty, 
           A.ord order_a, 
           B.ord order_b,
           SUM(A.qty) sum_qty,
           SUM(A.ord)  sum_order
    FROM A
    INNER JOIN B  ON A.COD = B.COD
    GROUP BY A.order_A,    B.order_B

    ) t
```